# android app installed on chrome os sd card path

Tags: javascript, android, visual-studio, cordova, google-chrome-os

chromeos now allows android apps to access the SD card [- link to ticket](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660189).  So what is the path that the android app should use for the SD card?

I am working on an android cordova app and using the ["file" plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file) and I need a read only path to the SD card.  The file plugins "externalRootDirectory" is not correct, so what path should I use for a file:///path/to/sd-card?